# How to scroll and selecting a value from drop-down in android Appium?

Tags: android, appium

I am testing a app in Appium in which I am opening a drop-down which opens a layout from I am taking following xpath to select a value to fill dropdown with it, but I am unable to do with this

```
driver.findElement(By.
      xpath("//android.widget.CheckedTextView[@text='Educational Payment']")).click();


//Also tried with [@index='2'] and by providing class hierarchy like below; 
//driver.findElement(By.
     //xpath("//android.widget.ListView.CheckedTextView[@text='Educational Payment']")).click();
```

and how to scroll that list there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code for scrolling:

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"**Element Name**\"));");
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the scrolling faster? I find the default scrolling really slow

Comment: Is it possible to scroll to the other direction, like from bottom to top?

Answer (score 0):

To scroll the screen till the desired text use following line of code:

```
 driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(newUiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"Educational Payment\"));");
```

Comment: how to select that option by click() function, when I call click() function, nothing happens.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,9000);   
 WebElement button=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpath of element to be clickeed")));
    button.click();